# How to disable ripple effect on long press of a button in lollipop?

Tags: android, material-design, android-view, android-appcompat, ripple-effect

How to disable ripple effect on long press of a button in lollipop?

When using sherlock long press of a button is not showing ripple effect but when i use appcompat it is showing a ripple effect on click and also on long click of a button .
I do not want any ripple effect on the press of a button

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button), then set `app:rippleColor`:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    ...
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

<sub>Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588798/8583692) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54155826/8583692) answer for their help.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

If you have root, have a look at my patch here https://github.com/luv/android5_noripple

My patch simply replaces draw function in android.graphics.drawable.Ripple with a function that does nothing but returns True.

You need to fetch /system/framework/framework.jar from your phone, patch it, and push it back (you need root for this). See the link for step-by-step instructions.

Comment: The link is broken, please include excerpts when posting solutions from a remote source. That way the solution will still be available for future readers.