# Set background color of button without removing ripple effect

Tags: android, button

I would like to change the background color of a button without removing the ripple effect/shadow/hover effect.

I also would like a solution that does not re-implement the ripple effect as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327188/android-setting-background-color-of-button-loses-ripple-effect).

It should also work on at least KitKat and above.

---

Here's a list of things I've tried that do not work:

1. ```
   Button.setBackgroundColor(0x2200FF00);
   ```

   Changes the background color of a button, but it removes the ripple effect, the shadow, and all visual aesthetics of a standard android material button.
2. ```
   Button.setBackgroundTintList(Context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.Blue));

   android:backgroundTint="#0000FF"
   ```

   Works, but not on KitKat (API >= 21).
3. ```
   <style name="ButtonBlue">
       <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorBlue</item>
   </style>

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       Button.setTextAppearance(R.style.ButtonBlue);
   } else {
       Button.setTextAppearance(Context, R.style.ButtonBlue);
   }
   ```

   Only works when defined in XML, setTextAppearance does not dynamically change the theme.

   ```
   android:theme="@style/ButtonBlue"
   ```

---

Is it possible to dynamically set the button's background color like this?

Comment: use CardView instead..

Comment: CardView was added in API 24 -> which is android 7 N. Way too new to be used when I need to support KitKat.

Comment: CardView is separate library it nothing has to do with API level

Comment: this question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327188/android-setting-background-color-of-button-loses-ripple-effect?noredirect=1&lq=1