# How to disable the Android ripple effect for quick taps?

Tags: android, material-design, android-view, android-5.0-lollipop

In certain apps like Google Play, quickly tapping / clicking views do not show a ripple effect.

If you long press an element the ripple is shown.

How is this effect achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try set properties view in layout:
 android:clickable="false"

Comment: The view needs to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You need to set other selector on that view. Ripple effect uses sectors which have "ripple" node in the xml.  Just use old type of selectors for Android <21 and it should work tag you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `app:rippleColor` attribute (if Material design library is used). So if you want to disable the ripple effect on a `Button` for example, set its ripple color to *transparent*:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    ...
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

I've already answered [anther similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31263828/8583692).